# cURL isn't working when accessing an API

Tags: api, curl

The code below is not working when I access the API by accessing this file and using cURL, It gives me following error:

Curl Error
Results
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden X-Mashery-Responder: mashery-web2-lax.mashery.com X-Mashery-Error-Code: ERR_403_DEVELOPER_INACTIVE Content-Type: text/xml Accept-Ranges: bytes Content-Length: 31 Server: Mashery Proxy Date: Mon, 29 Oct 2012 18:41:23 GMT Connection: keep-alive
403 Developer Inactive

and It is working when I access it directly through the link it generates. Can some one tell me if there is any problem with how I am using the cURL ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

/**
 * Initialize the cURL session
 */
$ch = curl_init();

$city = 'Seattle';
$departure = '11/03/2012';
$arrival = '11/08/2012';
$citycode='US';
$apiKey='***************';
$cid='55505';
$locale='en_US';
$currencyCode='USD';
$minorRev='16';
$customerSessionId='0ABAA874-27EB-E913-A4E2-7B0946904C6D';
$customerIpAddress=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$customerUserAgent=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];



$customerUserAgent=urlencode($customerUserAgent);

$url='http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?minorRev='.$minorRev.'&amp;cid='. $cid .'&amp;apiKey='. $apiKey.'&amp;customerUserAgent='.$customerUserAgent . '&amp;locale='.$locale.'&amp;currencyCode='.$currencyCode.'&_type=xml';


$xml='&lt;HotelListRequest&gt;&lt;city&gt;';
$xml .= $city;
$xml .='&lt;/city&gt;&lt;countryCode>';
$xml .= $citycode;
$xml .='&lt;/countryCode&gt;&lt;arrivalDate&gt;';
$xml .= $arrival;
$xml .='&lt;/arrivalDate&gt;&lt;departureDate&gt;';
$xml .= $departure;
$xml .='&lt;/departureDate&gt;&lt;/HotelListRequest&gt;';


$main = $url .'&xml='. $xml;
echo $main;
 /**
 * Set the URL of the page or file to download.
 */
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $main);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 65000);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/xml" ));
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );





 /**
 * Ask cURL to return the contents in a variable instead of simply echoing them to  the browser.
 */
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

 /**
 * Execute the cURL session
 */
 $contents = curl_exec ($ch);


 /**
 * Close cURL session
 */
 curl_close ($ch);

 echo '<br /><br />Curl Error';
echo curl_error($ch);
echo '<br />Results <br />' . $contents;


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your $url construction, don't encode the **ampersands** with **&amp;** between each parameter. The parameter values (e.g. "xml" param value) should be encoded, but the ampersands that delimit each GET request parameter in the URI should not be encoded.

So, your code creates this **$main** value:

```
http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?minorRev=16&amp;cid=55505&amp;apiKey=********&amp;customerUserAgent=&amp;locale=en_US&amp;currencyCode=USD&_type=xml&xml=&lt;HotelListRequest&gt;&lt;city&gt;Seattle&lt;/city&gt;&lt;countryCode>US&lt;/countryCode&gt;&lt;arrivalDate&gt;11/08/2012&lt;/arrivalDate&gt;&lt;departureDate&gt;11/03/2012&lt;/departureDate&gt;&lt;/HotelListRequest&gt;
```

And it should be:

```
http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?minorRev=16&cid=55505&apiKey=********&customerUserAgent=&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&_type=xml&xml=&lt;HotelListRequest&gt;&lt;city&gt;Seattle&lt;/city&gt;&lt;countryCode>US&lt;/countryCode&gt;&lt;arrivalDate&gt;11/08/2012&lt;/arrivalDate&gt;&lt;departureDate&gt;11/03/2012&lt;/departureDate&gt;&lt;/HotelListRequest&gt;
```

Take care,
Neil @ Mashery

Comment: For posterity, the API we're talking about here is the Expedia Affiliate Network API (http://developer.ean.com). It's an API for looking (price checks) and booking airfare, rental cars and hotel rooms, with API calls tied to affiliate revenue for the app developer.